# Generic app for mobile confirmation?

Tags: command-line, scripts, smartphone

I am looking for a way to have a strong confirmation from the user during sensitive operations from the command line or trigger by cron (sensitive script, decryption, etc...). Is there a generic application or a simple way to get this confirmation from the user without having to develop a dedicated mobile application ? Ideally biometrically.

Thanks for your idea !

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your need correctly, you could set up 2FA for typing passwords (including `sudo`).

For this to work you have to install and configure Google Authenticator (or similar app) on your phone (which is outside the scope of this site).

On Ubuntu, you have to do the following:

1. Install google authenticator: `sudo apt-get install libpam-google-authenticator`
2. Open the file `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` and look for the line:

   ```
   auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure
   ```
3. Above that line, add the following: (and then save and close):

   ```
   auth required pam_google_authenticator.so
   ```
4. Run this command from the terminal: `google-authenticator` (and answer `y` to every question). Do this for all users that have to use this.
5. After that, you'll get the secret key you can use to setup your Google Authenticator app on the phone.
6. When this is setup, the configured users will now have to type in a 6-digit code in addition to the password when doing `sudo` operations.

Link to the [full article](https://www.linux.com/topic/desktop/how-set-2-factor-authentication-login-and-sudo/).

Comment: Thank you, it is very interesting I didn't know that. Unfortunately it is not exactly what I am looking for:
- I would like to be able to interact on other actions than authentication
- I want to be able to validate an action remotely, without having to connect to the machine (the action can be initiated by a third party or by a cron). So a simple yes/no could be enough.

Comment: I'm not aware of that kind of solution though.